# Is it correct and natural to use "put out" in the sense of maiking something available, such as a product or transportation?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

Is it correct and natural to use *put out* in the sense of maiking something available, such as a product or transportation? For example:

> Because the buses are overcrowded athorities has decided to **put out** extra buses on the streets.
>
> The phone is in such high demand that the company decided to **put out** more phones.

If doesn't sound good, then what would native English speakers use instead of *put out*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is pretty reasonable, certainly understandable, though I would have written it as `... decided to put _on_ extra buses...`

Your second example is also understandable, but not entirely natural to me - it would make sense in some cases, if we were talking about a shop taking stock from their back room and `putting it out on the shelves` but that doesn't really make sense with phones or similar items. The normal usage in that regard would be `Company A put out a new phone today` which would mean that they had released an entirely new model, (which isn't what you meant, is it?)

Instead how about: `The phone ... company decided to make more phones available` or maybe `The phone ... company decided to manufacture more phones.`